# How do you implement help (using mallard) for a gtk3 app?

Tags: gtk3, mallard

I am trying to create my own gtk3 application. I like to use mallard to display some help about how to use my application. However I do not know how to code such that when the help menu item is clicked the help (mallard) is shown. I have the .page files already ready.

Please note, I am not asking how to create help files using mallard. **But rather how to integrate mallard into my gtk3 help.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question. In cases like this, I always look on git.gnome.org to see how Gedit does it. That's an excellent 'example' application.

First, look [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/help) at how they organize their help files:

```
help
  \--C
  |  \--*.page
  \--Makefile.am
  \--ar
  \--bg
  \--ca
  \--...other languages...
```

In `help/Makefile.am`, they use `@YELP_HELP_RULES@` to install the files (which is set up by `YELP_HELP_INIT` in `configure.ac`.)

Then, when the user clicks Help/Contents, they open the URI `help:gedit` or `help:gedit/link_id` with `gtk_show_uri()` (see [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-app.c), in the functions `gedit_app_show_help_impl()` and `gedit_app_help_link_id_impl()`) The files are then, presumably, automatically fetched by the desktop help system, translated into the proper language, and displayed in Yelp.